# Calculate distance between Mouse and the Edges of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to calculate the distance between the mouse and the Edges of a given element. So when the mouse touches the edge of the element the value should read 0px;

https://codepen.io/nishaljohn/pen/BVmGbz

```
var mX, mY, distance,
    $distance = $('#distance_text p'),
    $element  = $('.div1');

function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
}

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
    mX = e.pageX;
    mY = e.pageY;
    distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
    $distance.text(distance);         
});
```

This takes into account the centre of the element and reads 0px only when you reach the absolute centre.

#### A JQuery Plugin would also be fine.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: If you look at the example you will see that it returns distance as 0 only when it reaches the absolute centre of the element, I want it to read 0 as the mouse **touches** the element, and while the mouse is inside the element.

Comment: I think is just math...Add the height and width, the height and width of your object. Calc them outside and then add them on calculateDistance...It's not hard...

Comment: @Cristian I'm Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean, could you possibly show an edited pen of your proposed solution?

Comment: @PereraJohn Ok ill put an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any size element I used this code I found in another example:

```
var mX = e.pageX;
var mY = e.pageY;
var from = {x:mX, y:mY};
var $n=your_Element;
var off = $n.offset(),
  nx1 = off.left,
  ny1 = off.top,
  nx2 = nx1 + $n.outerWidth(),
  ny2 = ny1 + $n.outerHeight(),
  maxX1 = Math.max(mX, nx1),
  minX2 = Math.min(mX, nx2),
  maxY1 = Math.max(mY, ny1),
  minY2 = Math.min(mY, ny2),
  intersectX = minX2 >= maxX1,
  intersectY = minY2 >= maxY1,
  to = {
    x: intersectX ? mX : nx2 < mX ? nx2 : nx1,
    y: intersectY ? mY : ny2 < mY ? ny2 : ny1
  };
var distX = to.x - from.x,
  distY = to.y - from.y,
  hypot = Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY);
console.log(hypot);//this will output 0 when next to your element.
```

Comment: I tested and it worked very well, some examples working: https://jsfiddle.net/Byte/L9hv4pcr (jQuery), https://jsfiddle.net/Byte/L5nzt7af (Vanilla JS)

Comment: You should link to wherever you got this code from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is just pure math. It's just about to take away the width and the height of the container `- elem.width()/2` and  `- elem.height()/2`

```js
(function() {
    
    var mX, mY, distance,
        $distance = $('#distance span'),
        $element  = $('#element');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) - elem.width()/2 + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2) ) -elem.height()/2);
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
        if(distance > 0)
         $distance.text(distance);
        else{
        $distance.text(0);
        }
    });

})();
```

```css
body {
    font: 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;    
}

#distance {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
}

#element {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Move your mouse to calculate distance between the center of the element and the mouse cursor.</p>

<p id="distance">Distance: <span>0</span>px</p>

<div id="element"></div>
```

Is this the solution?

Comment: Your solution does indeed work, but it works for a perfect square. I tested it out for a rectangle and it only works for the height. The width remains more than 0 when at the edge.

Comment: one solution I found is to use this library

http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-dom-line/

It draws a line from mouse to the edge of an element, you can make the line invisible and use jquery to get the width of the element afterwards.
Its definitely not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Also you can apply math for any kind of shapes.Your solution is much better

Comment: You should [give credit to Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/calculate-distance-between-mouse-and-element/) for the function. Using code without credit is bad.

Comment: This only calculates the distance to an element's center, which is not what the OP asked for.